# How to see the transpiled typescript from webpack babel-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack

As title. It's a bit embarrassing that while I know how to do the followings, I still don't know how to achieve what the title suggested:

1. I know how to setup `.eslintrc.json` to work with `tsconfig.json`. (This is actually very tricky if you want to set all these things up: TypeScript, react, react-jsx, `"parserOptions"` that requires some changes in `tsconfig.json`, etc)
2. I know how to setup `babel.config.js` to work with `webpack.config.js`. (The only thing I know is that Babel can read TypeScript, so I only need to use `babel-loader`)

How to the result `.js` of the process "TypeScript --> JavaScript --> Old-Version-JavaScript"? These are parts of the `webpack.config.js` I think relevant:

```js
export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(curDir, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(curDir, 'docs'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',   // should I delete this?
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { cacheCompression: false },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

and `babel.config.js`: (and Yes I'm using the syntax of the ES6 module, or ESM if you preferred)

```js
export default {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',                // I don't know what this one is doing?
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
  ],
}
```

This is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",

    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "allowJs": true,

    "noEmit": true,

    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "strict": false,

    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "./*.config.*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "**/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In short I want to the the result similar to run:

```
npx tsc --watch
```

and then follows by

```
npx babel out.js
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the `webpack.config.js` you provided, it seems that you were only using `babel-loader` to transpile your code. This means that the `tsc` will not be used, and thus that the `tsconfig.json` is not related to solving your question meant by the title.

> How to the result .js of the process "TypeScript --> JavaScript --> Old-Version-JavaScript"?

In your case `babel-loader` is responsible for both the two arrows. (with the the `@babel/preset-typescript` from `babel.config.js` for the first one and `@babel/preset-env` for the second one)

> ```json
> @babel/preset-env',                // I don't know what this one is doing?
> ```

It's going to transpile your javascript code to (possibly) an older version JS based on your `browserslist` targets. Please refer to the docs for more details: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env.

Finally, the answer to your question is based on your `webpack.config.js`, again:

```js
  // ...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(curDir, 'docs'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[contenthash].js',
    clean: true,
  },
  // ...
```

The transpiled result is in the file you specified in this `output` section. You probably targeted browsers that are too new so nothing need to be transpiled.